# Compare string and map value

Tags: c++, string, comparison, maps

I'm trying to compare two strings

One string is a normal string that I got from an istringstream:

```
string command;
iss >> command;
```

and the other is a string that I get from my map.

But it does not seem to be working.

The idea is that I have a `map<string, string>`, the value is to be an
escape code to change the terminal output colour.

I have a map in my `main` that I put all the keys and values into
(which works, I've tested that) so I pass the map into this function.

I also have defined colours at the top of my program:

```
#define BLACK "\033[22;30m"
#define RED "\033[22;31m"
#define GREEN "\033[22;32m"
#define BROWN "\033[22;33m"
#define BLUE "\033[22;34m"
#define PURPLE "\033[22;35m"
#define CYAN "\033[22;36m"
#define GREY "\033[22;37m"
#define DARK_GREY "\033[01;30m"
#define LIGHT_RED "\033[01;31m"
#define LIGHT_GREEN "\033[01;32m"
#define YELLOW "\033[01;33m"
#define LIGHT_BLUE "\033[01;34m"
#define LIGHT_PURPLE "\033[01;35m"
#define LIGHT_CYAN "\033[01;36m"
#define WHITE "\033[01;37m"
```

This is the part that seems not to be working and confusing me:

```
string getColor(string command, map<string, string> &m)
{
  string color;
  if((m.find(command)->second).compare(RED) == 0)
  {
    color = RED;
    return color;
  }
  // ...and so on for all the other colors
}
```

I would have made this a `switch`, but C++ doesn't allow switches on strings.

So the problem is, even if the both strings are the same, it's not working like that.

I realize that `m.find()` is returning an iterator at the position of what we are looking for. 
But then doing `m.find()->second` should get to the value right?
And the value is a string, isn't it?

So in short, I'm not sure why the comparison isn't working.

**EDIT:**

Ok, here is the config file I was talking about:

```
bold           \e[0;31m 
italic         \e[0;34m
underline      \e[0;32m 
default        \e[0;37m
```

so the user input would be something like:

(default this is a(bold simple) example.)

so when I get the command "default", I will search in my map for that string, and then get the colour code associated with it.

then I will change the output colour to the colour in the map associated with default.
then I will change the output colour to the colour associated in the map with "bold" to print out the word "simple", and then I will go back to the previous colour to print out the rest of the sentence.

but because when I do this:

```
cout << config.find("bold")->second << " hi" << endl;
```

it doesn't change the colour, it prints out:

\e[0;31m hi

instead of changing the output colour :/

so I thought I'd do a comparison, because something like this:

```
cout << RED << "hi" << endl;
```

will print out hi in the colour red.

Comment: ewwwwwwwwwww macros bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do a very complicated map lookup. Wouldn't this work?

```
    const string & getColor(string command, const map<string, string> & m)
    {
        map<string,string>::const_iterator i = m.find(command);
        return i == m.end() ? BLACK : i->second;
    }
```

Of course, this does not address the issue of supposedly equal strings not comparing equal. You will need to post a more complete example for us to be able to answer that, I think. But the first answer about embedded null characters is mistaken. What you have is embedded escape characters, which is fully correct. The only thing I would do different there is to use const char * RED = etc. instead of #defines, since variables are easier to deal with than macros.

Edit: Seems like the answer I was referring to here disappeared.

Edit2: How does this compare to what you are trying to do? It works for me, at least:

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;

    #define BLACK "\033[22;30m"
    #define RED "\033[22;31m"
    #define GREEN "\033[22;32m"

    const string & getColor(const string & command, const map<string, string> & m)
    {
        map<string,string>::const_iterator i = m.find(command);
        return i == m.end() ? BLACK : i->second;
    }

    int main() {
        map<string,string> cols;
        cols["BLACK"] = BLACK;
        cols["RED"]   = RED;
        cols["GREEN"] = GREEN;

        string line, cmd, val;
        while(getline(cin, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            if(ss >> cmd >> val && cmd == "color:")
                cout << getColor(val, cols);
            else cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
```

The input

```
This text is default color
color: RED
This text is red
color: GREEN
This text is green
```

should produce the colors indicated.

Edit3: In light of your new information, it seems like the real problem is that your config file contains does not contain actual escape characters, just the characters '\' and 'e'. Make sure your file actually contains real escape characters. How to generate these varies from editor to editor. In vim, you would type an escape by doing ctrl-V followed by escape. In the worst case, you can generate this by printing them from your own C program - you already have the defines, after all: `fprintf(conffile, "bold %s\n", BOLD)`.

Comment: it is a bit complicated. The point is, I'm mapping a config file; it will tell me what the command is and what the corresponding colour is.

Once I have that mapped, I take in lines from standard in, and when a command is specified, I have to change the output colour to the colour associated with the command. But I can't change the colour using it->second after finding the command because it just prints out the string instead of changing the colour, which is really odd. So I need to do a comparison...but even that is proving difficult. It seems that it->second isn't giving me a string :/

Comment: ok, I've edited my original post to give a little more information on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see. That would make sense. I'm using cygwin, I'll have to look into that. This was just how the config file was specified to be written in the assignment outline. I'll have to ask my instructor about this. Thank you

Comment: If the input really has to be in that format, you could search for the substring "\\e" and replace it with a proper escape string "\e". I.e. string.find and string.replace. You would do this while reading in the configuration file.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It turned out to be that it wasn't reading \e as an escape character, but rather two separate characters; as amaurea suggested. So I fixed that and now it works fine.